# How can I install two different versions of MongoDB and use them parallelly on Windows?

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have `MongoDB v3.2` installed on my local machine and I am using it for my node application. I want to install `MongoDB v3.4` to test some of the features which do not have anything to do with the existing node application. (ie) I want to install and use both of them at the same time on the same machine. Is it possible to do so in Windows? Will it create any port related issues? I could not find any relevant articles or help on SO or any other websites. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should consider using [docker](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows]) for this.

Comment: I believe you just have to make sure different ports will be used by 3.2 and 3.4 mongod services. By default uses port 27017. You can provide port number in config https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options

Comment: and dbpath along with port